# Tableview can not scroll to bottom

Tags: uitableview, scroll

I have a tableview can not scroll to bottom, i can send the whole source code for check if need, thanks everyone ~~

[case video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2QBE.gif)

This is full source code, input CM02165 and search, wait few seconds, will return a result set from web service for testing.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1k50yqiv7yhh4iv/IMXSE.zip?dl=0

I really no idea.... anyone can help? SOS~

Comment: Looks like it's Auto Layout issue, instead of code issue. Make sure all constraints are set correctly.

Comment: the constraints setting all disabled, i can not edit.... any idea?

Comment: Disabled? You shouldn't disable Auto Layout constraints.

Comment: I do not disabled auto layout constraints, but i dont know why i can't edit